# Is it possible to get the date-year attribute of a period index or period range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to obtain the Fiscal Year of a company that has its quarters end on the last Friday of the quarter where the fiscal year start is May and the fiscal year end month is April. I get the calendar year of the quarter end year when I ask for the calendar year attribute of a Periodindex (and I understand why and that I can get quarter start).  But can I get around that while still setting my fiscal quarters with an offset?

## list of dates - test data

```
first_date = datetime(2017, 1, 1)
last_date = datetime(2019, 9, 20)
x = 30
list_of_dates = [date for date in np.arange(first_date, last_date, timedelta(days=x)).astype(datetime)]
```

## create the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': list_of_dates})
```

## create index

```
idx = pd.PeriodIndex(df.dates, freq='Q-APR')

df['fscl_YrQtr'] = idx
df['calendar_Yr'] = idx.year
df['fscl_Yr'] = idx.qyear
df['fscl_Qtr'] = idx.quarter
```

## The Following all work except the last one (df['fscl_year_huh']) that just gives me 2018 continuously.  I can't figure that one out.

```
df['Q_end_date'] = [date - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1) + pd.tseries.offsets.FY5253Quarter(normalize=True, weekday=4,startingMonth=4, qtr_with_extra_week=1, variation='last') for date in  df.dates]
df['fscl_year_quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex([date - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1) + pd.tseries.offsets.FY5253Quarter(normalize=True, weekday=4,startingMonth=4, qtr_with_extra_week=1, variation='last') for date in  df.dates], freq='Q-APR')
df['month'] = df.dates.dt.month
df['year'] = df.dates.dt.year
df['fscl_days_of_period'] = pd.PeriodIndex([date - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1) + pd.tseries.offsets.FY5253Quarter(normalize=True, weekday=4,startingMonth=4, qtr_with_extra_week=1, variation='last') for date in  df.dates], freq='Q-APR').day
df['fscl_quarter_num'] = pd.PeriodIndex([date - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1) + pd.tseries.offsets.FY5253Quarter(normalize=True, weekday=4,startingMonth=4, qtr_with_extra_week=1, variation='last') for date in  df.dates], freq='Q-APR').quarter
df['fscl_year_huh'] = pd.PeriodIndex([date - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1) + pd.tseries.offsets.FY5253Quarter(normalize=True, weekday=4,startingMonth=4, qtr_with_extra_week=1, variation='last') for date in  df.dates], freq='Q-APR').year
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is pythonic, but I solved the issue by leveraging loc:

```
df.loc[((df.dates.dt.month >= 5) | ((df.dates.dt.month == 4) & (df['fscl_quarter_num'] == 1))), 'fiscl_year'] = df.dates.dt.year + 1
df.loc[((df.dates.dt.month <= 4) & (df['fscl_quarter_num'] != 1)), 'fiscl_year'] = df.dates.dt.year
```

any month of May or beyond gets a fiscal year uptick.  any month of April where the fiscal month ends before the end of the month will have a fiscal quarter of 1 for the end of the month.